# How can disable the keyboard input in MUI datepick V5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

In the past, I used DatePicker in @material-ui/date-pickers, which only allow picker.

In my project, I upgraged to MUI V5 and follow this doc
https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/migration-lab/

```
-import { DatePicker } from '@material-ui/pickers';
+import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker';


 <DatePicker
    label="Basic example"
    value={value}
    onChange={(newValue) => {
      setValue(newValue);
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
  />
```

After migrated to v5, the compoent allows keyboard input, which cause an issue in my system.

It is because our system's date format displays with "dd-MMM-yyyy". If the compenent allows the keyboard input, it will cause some probelms with using this format 'dd-MMM-yyyy'. Hence, I hope to disable the keyboard input only allow the picker.

May I know how can disable it?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. Added the "readOnly: true" to TextField's inputProps.

```
<DatePicker
    label="Basic example"
    value={value}
    onChange={(newValue) => {
      setValue(newValue);
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        inputProps={{
          ...params.inputProps,
          readOnly: true
        }}
      />
    )}
  />
```